# Why doesn't this compile, about java comparables?

Tags: java

I want to implement the priority queue using heap. The queue is to store objects of type Entry: K V, where K and V are key/value pairs. But I'm having difficulty using the compareTo method that I implemented in the class Entry. It won't compile.

```java
public class Entry <K extends Comparable,V> implements Comparable<Entry>{
    K key;
    V value;

    public int compareTo(Entry other) {
        return key.compareTo(other.key);
    }
}


public class PQ <Entry>{
    Object[] queue;

    public int compareEntries(Entry e1, Entry e2) {
             return (e1.compareTo( e2));
    }
}
```

in the last line (e1.compareTo(e2)), the compareTo is highlighted and doesn't compile. It asks me to cast e1 but it autocasts to nonsense. But I don't get why it won't compile.

Comment: What is the exact compilation error?

Comment: You should strip the code down to the minimum needed to show your problem.

Comment: When you compile with code, do you see any warnings?  They're important.

Comment: By the way, why not use [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) rather than define your own? Note the [`comparingByKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByKey()) method.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman the warning is The method CompareTo<Entry> is undefined for type Entry.

Comment: @Slaw the problem is the last line won't compile. the compareTo method is highlighted red.

Comment: @Basil Bourque it's an assignment and I'm not allowed to use any data structure other than array.

Comment: Well, for starters, it should be `class Entry<K implements Comparable<K>, V> implements Comparable<Entry<K>, V>`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
public class PQ <Entry>{
```

That's declaring "Entry" as a placeholder for a generic type, and **not** specifying that you want to use your `Entry` class.  You want to either remove `<Entry>` completely, or, if this needs to be generic, do the following:

```
public class PQ <T extends Entry>{
  Object[] queue;

  public int compareEntries(T e1, T e2) {
    return (e1.compareTo( e2));
  }
}
```

And then, when you create an instance of your class, you can do this:

```
PQ<Entry> pq = new PQ();
```

But unless you need `PQ` to accept more types than `Entry`, the better solution is to just delete the `<Entry>` part entirely, so that your class definition is simply:

```
public class PQ {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the 'Entry' you think you are.

```
class PQ <Entry>
```

You are creating a new generic type parameter called 'Entry'. Since it's unbounded, you are using this identifier when conventionally people would use `T`, standing for 'type'. The fact that your generic type parameter has the same name as your class is purely coincidental.

You probably want something like this:

```
public class PQ <K extends Comparable<K>, V>{
    Object[] queue;

    public int compareEntries(Entry<K, V> e1, Entry<K, V> e2) {
             return (e1.compareTo( e2));
    }
}
```

Your Entry class is also likely wrong. You probably want

```
public class Entry <K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements Comparable<Entry<K, V>>{
```

Notice that any given Entry is **only comparable** to entries with the same types. Because how can you compare two entries if the keys are different types? How do you compare an int and a string? A string and a boolean? etc

Comment: Thanks! But in this case what does <K,V> mean ? My purpose is to store key/value pairs in an array. if I have both K and V in the PQ, how can I store them both in one slot?

Comment: Key and Value, the same as in your entry. "how can I store them both in one slot?" I don't know what this means

Comment: I mean for example if I have a class Entry<K,V>, then by storing instances of Entry class I can store both keys and values in the Object[] queue. So in that case it should be PQ<T extends Entry> or something? But you showed me another way which seems to be what the assignment is about. I'm just not understanding fully the mechanics here.

Comment: Why do you want an array of Objects anyway? It seems like it should be `Queue<Entry<K, V>>`

Comment: I can't use other data structures than array. Also since I was putting in a generic "Entry" for PQ class, I couldn't make Entry[] queue=new Entry[10] for example, so I had to use object[]. But I'm totally confused right now and may be on the wrong path. But I really think your answer might be what the teacher want but I don't get how to store both K,V in an array in this case.

Comment: The issue is that your array should hold Entries which are generic but arrays cannot be generic. `Entry[] queue=new Entry[10]` is fine by the way. It's using the raw type, but there's nothing you can do about that **if you must use an array**. It's better than `Object[]` though, even though that will not give a warning. When retrieving items from the array, you will just have to cast it I suppose. `(Entry<K, V>) queue[0]` etc